# Player is dying while colliding with enemy while adding score Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collision-detection

I'm stuck at at. I'm trying to give scores to player when laser hit the enemy. there are two main if conditions. one is when enemy will collide with player, enemy will be destroyed and also costs 1 damage to player.
and in the second case if enemy hit the laser it will add the score to player.

"I have created this player variable on global and initialize on start"

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour{

public float speedofenemy = 1.0f;
private Player player;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Player>();
}
```

after adding score destroy the enemy and the laser. but what happens is when my player collide with enemy it just destroyed first time. i don't understand why?
Please Help.

```
  void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{

    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {

        Destroy(this.gameObject);

        Player player = other.transform.GetComponent<Player>();
        if (player != null)
            player.Damage();
    }

    if (other.tag == "Laser")

        if (player != null) {
            player.addScore(10);
        }

        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    Destroy(this.gameObject);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are destroying your player, you need to change your code like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{

    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {

        Destroy(this.gameObject);

        Player player = other.transform.GetComponent<Player>();
        if (player != null)
            player.Damage();
    }

    if (other.tag == "Laser")
    {
        if (player != null) {
            player.addScore(10);
        }
    
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
     }
    
    Destroy(this.gameObject);

}
```

Comment: The code worked for me is:
if (other.tag == "Laser")
    {
        if (player != null) {
            player.addScore(10);
        }
    
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
 }